# How to install ClearOS community edition 6.5.0 from USB drive?

Tags: installation, clearos, usb-flash-drive

Due to the fact that pfSense 2.1 wouldn't detect our Thunderbolt Broadcom NetXtreme BCM57762 gigabit ethernet adapter, we are having a look at ClearOS.

For ClearOS 6.5.0 community edition we couldn't find a USB installer, and the ClearOS CD fails to install correctly. During the installation procedure the anaconda installer aborts due to unavailable installation media. Unavailable media might be caused by our Teac USB CD-ROM drive that goes into power saving mode and then takes too long to spin back up.

We can find a [USB installer for ClearOS Enterprise 5.1](http://www.clearcenter.com/support/documentation/clearos_enterprise_5.1/user_guide/starting_the_install), which is not the ClearOS version we desire. [UNetbootin 5.8.5](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) doesn't create a USB drive that is bootable. And [Rufus 1.4.1](http://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus_v1.4.1.exe) creates a bootable USB stick that stops with a failure during the installation procedure due to unavailable installation source files. How to create a bootable USB stick that installs ClearOS community edition 6.5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to create a USB installer for ClearOS community edition using Rufus is quite simple.

You only need to **copy** the `.iso` file (`clearos-community-6.5.0-x86_64.iso`) **to the root** of the USB installation media **after** preparing the media with **Rufus** for boot and installation.

Now the clearOS installation procedure no longer fails in the middle, and after reboot your can login to the console with default ClearOS username "root" and the password you created.

Answer (score 1):

Just use YUMI multiboot usb creator. 
Download it and run it then the steps are as follows:

Step 1: Select usb drive ( and choose the option to format drive)

Step 2: Select a distribution (go to the bottom of the dropdown list and choopspe the option for "unlisted syslinux ISO

Step 3: Browse (to the CentOS  ISO you downloaded)

Now just click  "create" and wait until YUMI finishes and you will have a bootable USB drive with CentOS on it ready for installation.

Comment: Was able to boot this way, but get stuck at the Select Partition point; where it wants the partition with the install image. The default path did not include the name of my clearos image folder. It worked fine after typing that into the path.